# Creating a category programmatically using category factory, category data gets created in DB, but category is not visible in admin

Tags: category, programmatically, create, factory

Pretty much self-explanatory.

I create a category model using category factory and then use the **->save** method to save the category. I can see some data created, along with **catalog_category_entity**, but the category is not visible in admin.
This is the code that I use:

```
public function createCategory($categoryName="", $categoryDescription="", $parentCategoryId=2, $position=1) {

        /// Add a new sub category under root category
        $categoryTmp = $this->cf->create();
        $categoryTmp->setName($categoryName);
        $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
        $categoryTmp->setUrlKey("cat-" . $categoryName);
        $categoryTmp->setData("description", $categoryDescription);
        $categoryTmp->setParentId($parentCategoryId);
        $categoryTmp->setStoreId(0);
        $categoryTmp->setPath("2");

        $categoryTmp->save(); //Using this save method, because the perfion import procedure is not time-demanding 
        return $categoryTmp;
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess would be 1) Not assigned inside Root Category which is Default category. 2) Store not assigned.

Comment: I assign it under an existing category. StoreId is also assigned.